# Small issue with str_replace

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
$produrl = '/'. basename(str_replace(".html","",$_cat->getUrl())) .'/' . basename($_product->getProductUrl()) ;
```

`$_cat->getUrl()` returns this:

http://website.com/category/subcategory.html

I need: for $produrl part of `basename(str_replace(".html","",$_cat->getUrl()))`to return `category/subcategory`

The issue:

It gives back only `category` without `/subcategory` I know the issue is in the str_replace it's wrong isn't? Can you help me with that?

Pleast Note I have 2 Cases:

1. Sometimes I get `http://website.com/category/subcategory.html`.
2. Sometimes `http://website.com/category.html`

And I would like it to work with both of them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use parse_url instead:

```
$url = parse_url($_cat->getUrl());
$produrl = str_replace(".html","",$url['path']);
```

Comment: I have updated my question I have 2 Cases sometimes I get http://website.com/category/subcategory.html and sometimes http://website.com/category.html does it still will work for it?

Comment: yes parse_url and the path part gives you everything after the domain name. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Look at the link to the `parse_url()` function. $url in this case is the result array you get from parse_url. Everything that is after the domain name is stored with the key 'path'

Comment: wow it's such a great function! In sense of performance it's not heavy?

Comment: I personally have never benchmarked it but I highly doubt you will suffer any performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using the `basename()` function.

Take a look at the documentation for it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

It will only return the trailing string after the "/" (forward slash) or "\" (back slash, for Windows).

Comment: Yep I have checked that but I have no idea what method should I use to make it work and please note I have 2 cases Sometimes I get http://website.com/category/subcategory.html and sometimes http://website.com/category.html